# quitar dos ultimos ceros de una cantidad entera en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo una cantidad que es entero en mi BD pero yo solo leo esa cantidad y siempre le agrega dos ceros al final, por lo que estoy intentando quitar esos dos ceros de mas, he realizado un casteo como el siguiente

> CAST(RTRIM(CANTIDAD_ORIGINAL '0')  AS INTEGER) AS IMPORTE

pero me quita todos los ceros a la derecha de mi cifra, pero eso no me sirve, ya que me borra todos los ceros y  solo quiero eliminar los dos ultimos ceros de mi cantidad,por ejemplo si mi cantidad es 7000 me deja unicamente 7 y realmente la cantidad que necesito es 70, ¿Como podria quitar solo los dos ultimos ceros?

Comment: Y por que no atacas tu verdadero problema "siempre le agrega dos ceros al final", eso es un comportamiento muy raro de cualquier base de datos.

Comment: Mas bien parece que el comportamiento tiene que ver con la herramientas o la interfaz de usuario que usa para "ver" la información de la base datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 RTRIM(REPLACE(CANTIDAD_ORIGINAL, '00', '')) AS IMPORTE
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolverlo utilizando las funciones `SUBSTR` y `LENGTH` y un `case` para verificar si termina con dos ceros se eliminan estos en caso contrario se obtiene el mismo valor, ademas puedes utilizar `TO_NUMBER` para convertirlo a valor numerico

Ejemplo

```
SELECT CAST(case when SUBSTR(CANTIDAD_ORIGINAL,-2)='00' then SUBSTR(CANTIDAD_ORIGINAL,0,LENGTH(message)-2) else CANTIDAD_ORIGINA end AS INTEGER) AS IMPORTE
```

Con `TO_NUMBER`

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(case when SUBSTR(CANTIDAD_ORIGINAL,-2)='00' then SUBSTR(CANTIDAD_ORIGINAL,0,LENGTH(message)-2) else CANTIDAD_ORIGINA end) AS IMPORTE
```